# how to bind the radio button with combobox in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hi I have comobox with some values (user select only one item) and I want acording to that select that the user will be allow to select multiselection from radiobutton.
for example: comobox of elemnt- user select one element and after that select many crops grom radiobutton.
I cant connect between those both. pls HELP
my code:

```
def calibration_window():
    global cb_elemnt,cb_crop
    top = tkinter.Toplevel (window)
    top.title ("Calibration")
    top.geometry ("400x400")
    ttk.Label (top, text="Select an element:",font = ("Segoe UI Light", 10)).grid (column=0, row=0)
    cb_elemnt = ttk.Combobox (top, values=ele_list)
    cb_elemnt.grid(column=0, row=1)
    ttk.Label (top, text="Select a crop:",font = ("Segoe UI Light", 10)).grid (column=2, row=0)
    # connect between element comobox to the func
    cb_elemnt.bind ("<<ComboboxSelected>>",set_radio)



def set_radio(event):
    i=0
    radios=[]
    for widget in radios:
        widget.destroy ()
    radios = []
    if StringVar().get() !="N":
         radio_values = pd.unique (df[df['elemnt'] == StringVar().get()]["crop"]) #take  the suitable crop from DB
    else:
        radio_values = pd.unique (df_nir[df_nir['elemnt'] == StringVar().get()]["crop"])

    for t in radio_values:
        i = i + 1
        b = Radiobutton (self, text=t, variable=IntVar(), value=t)
        b.grid (row=i, column=0)
        radios.append(b)
```

Comment: Please do proper code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your `IntVar` and the list `radio` outside of your function so they won't be garbage collected.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({"element":np.random.choice(["Elem A","Elem B","Elem C"], 20),
                   "crops": [f"Crop {i}" for i in range(20)]})

root = tk.Tk()

r_var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
radios=[]
ttk.Label(root, text="Select an element:",font=("Segoe UI Light", 10)).grid(column=0, row=0)
cb_elemnt = ttk.Combobox(root, values=df["element"].unique().tolist())
cb_elemnt.grid(column=0, row=1)
ttk.Label(root, text="Select a crop:",font=("Segoe UI Light", 10)).grid(column=2, row=0)

def set_radio(event):
    for widget in radios:
        widget.destroy()
    if cb_elemnt.get():
        radio_values = df.loc[df["element"].eq(cb_elemnt.get()),"crops"]
        for num, t in enumerate(radio_values, 1):
            b = tk.Radiobutton(root, text=t, variable=r_var, value=t)
            b.grid (row=num, column=1)
            radios.append(b)

cb_elemnt.bind ("<<ComboboxSelected>>", set_radio)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! what if instead radio button I would like to set Checkbutton  ( to allow multi select) Checkbutton  dont have parameter of value so what should I do?

Comment: Create one tkinter variable for each `Checkbutton` and configure `onvalue` and `offvalue`. See [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm) for details.